# KeyError every times upgrade Odoo module

Tags: odoo

I am new to Odoo, I developing a simple module that will add some fields to an existed view. First, I install it to Odoo, it works fine. Then I edit some code, likes add new more field to my module. Now when I upgrade my module with some new code, Odoo display error: KeyError "bla bla".
But if I install my new module to another machine, it works fine.
Did I miss something? How can I fix it.
And, sorry for my bad English, I'm Vietnamese.

Update my code:
my_model.py file:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class ij_project_form(osv.osv):
_name = 'project.project'
_inherit = "project.project"

_columns = {
    'ij_project_form_id': fields.integer('An integer field', size=11),
    'ij_project_form_des': fields.text('A text field')
}

_defaults ={
    'ij_project_form_id': 0
}

ij_project_form()
```

my_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="ij_project_form">
        <field name="name">project.project.form</field>
        <field name="model">project.project</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
                <newline/>
                <field name="ij_project_form_id" />
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr='//page[@string="Project Stages"]' position="after">
                <group string="Injection tab" name="sample">
                    <field name="ij_project_form_des" />
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Please put errors you faced with the question, you should try to update module after restart service.

Comment: I got this line: KeyError: 'project.project' from log file. I also tried update module after restarted service, but still error, and my service stopped right after started. Oh, and my module inherit from project module, project model too

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I updated my error code. Give me an advice, please!

Comment: Code is looking fine, no issue with code, try to elaborate error properly,  **KeyError: 'project.project'** is not enough to identify problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try another way

Answer (score 3):

Here you are inherit the  project.project model and this model is in project module so you are first set dependencies in v7,v8 **openerp**.py and if you work on v9 or v10 than **manifest**.py

> **'depends':['project']**

Answer (score 0):

1) In odoo the '_name' attribute creates a new table in the backend (i.e., in database). So, when you want to add fields to the existing model (like here 'project.project'), no need to use _name. "_inherit" like above is sufficient.

With the above code it will try to create another table, project_project (which is a base table of odoo, which is already created in database). so, remove the _name in your code and run.

We can use _name along with _inherit, but try to give different name to '_name' attribute. So this conflict wont be raised.

Comment: Hi @shravan, thanks for your answer.
But why with the same code, if I install it on another machine, it works, and if I tried to upgrade it from installed machine, it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your `__openerp__.py` file and make sure you place the `depends` section correctly.

Here, you inherit the `project.project` module, so you should add this in the `__openerp__.py`:

> 'depends': ['project']

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because here you are inheriting the project module. So in your module's manifest file you have to make depend on the project module
eg:
In your **openerp**.py file add the following code

'depends': [
   'project',
],

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This happens with every newcomer in odoo , I also suffered with this "KeyError". Well I changed database by creating new one and Installed all needed modules again. It worked for me .

And about your English ,In Communication words doesn't matter , only understanding is require.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm also new too odoo
I encountered same problem KeyError: 'some old model'
The reason is like other answers, due to stale data in the database

I fixed it by removing the records from db with this command

```
DELETE FROM ir_model WHERE model = 'yourmodule.oldmodelname';
```